# View XCode docset docs from terminal

Tags: xcode, xcode4, documentation, manpage

Is there some tool that can allow me to view an installed DocSet as something like a manpage? Maybe something along the lines of `ri` in ruby, `godoc` in Go, etc? I do most of my Objective-C coding in vim+Terminal and would like to be able to access and search the API docs from the terminal as well.

I've searched a good bit here on SO and have also seen a few 3p tools (`AppleDocs` seems nice, but appears geared for converting *to* DocSet, not *from* it) that are in the neighborhood, but nothing that I can find is set up to let me view from a shell.

Comment: You are coding only via vim ? You're like me, I go to work by horseback.

Comment: I don't ask you why you still use vim, it must be a good reason :)

Comment: You could just use the Organizer window of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Dash](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12). It's a GUI, but much more lightweight than opening Xcode just to use the organizer. It supports documentation searches from the command line using a custom URL scheme.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Even just being able to use or wrap a CLI to navigate would be a welcome change :)